# Existence of a uniform random variable on a probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be the probability space. Then a real value random variable $X$ is a measurable function from $X: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ (assumed $[0,1]$ for simplicity). Now I want to find that given any probability space, can I atleast construct one such $X$ such that $X$ is a uniform random variable or equivalently solving
$$P\big(X^{-1}[0,t)\big) = t, \;\; \forall t \in (0,1]$$
Some trivial non-examples would be $\mathcal{F} = \{\phi, \Omega\}$. I am interested in knowing in knowing what necessary condition guarantees the existence of such an $X$.

P.S. Motivation for choosing uniform distribution is once we have uniform distribution, then via composition, I can get any other distribution).

Comment: it's not true that given any probability space you can find a uniform r.v. (just take $\Omega =\{1\}$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal P(\Omega )$ and $\mathbb P(1)=1$... you can't construct a r.v. $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ that is "uniform") However, you can construct a probability space where there is a uniform r.v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, $\mathcal F$ must contain countably many *independent* fair coin tosses.

Suppose $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb[0,1)$ has a uniform distribution and let $X_n(\omega)\in\{0,1\}$ be the $n$-th bit in the proper binary decomposition of $X(\omega)$, i.e.,
$$X(\omega):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{X_n(\omega)}{2^n}\tag{$\star$},\quad\omega\in\Omega.$$
Then one can see that:

1. For each $n\ge1$, $X_n$ is a Bernoulli$(\frac12)$ random variable, e.g., $X_1=1$ means that $X\in[0,\frac12)$, while $X_2=1$ means that $X\in[\frac14,\frac12)\cup[\frac34,1)$, etc.
2. The variables $X_n,n\ge1,$ are independent, e.g., $$P(X_1=1, X_2=1)=P\!\left(X\in\left[\frac34,1\right)\!\right)=\frac14=P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1).$$

Conversely, if $(X_n:n\ge1)$ is a family of independent fair coin tosses on $\Omega$, then $X$ defined by $(\star)$ has the uniform distribution.